# How do I set a space between UICollectionViewCell and UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that I constrained to the edge of the screen. However, when the screen loads, I want the first cell to have some padding so it is positioned slightly off the left edge of the screen. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Space inside the collectionView

Answer (score 0):

You can control the padding  with below UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate functions :

```
extension YourCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout { 
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
          let width = collectionView.frame.width
          return CGSize(width: width/2 - (inset+padding), height: width/2 - (inset+padding))
      }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
         return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
      }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return 1.0
      }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return 1.0
      }
}
```